# Make a single exe cefsharp application - embedding libcef.dll - costura.fody

Tags: embed, cefsharp, fody-costura, assemblyresolve

I have tried many things before I found **costura.fody** and I were hoping that would be the solution to create a single file exe of a **cefsharp** application that I'm doing.

So the help file says set copy local to true of the file you want to embed in the solution explorer.
Done that.

So the exe got a little bit bigger when I did that but I notice that the size was not even close to cover **libcef.dll** so I suspected that this file was not embedded.

I tested this by renaming the dll in the output folder and yes I couldn't run the application.

I would really love for this to work but I'm kind of giving up.
I was struggling with **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve** to tap into that event but it was never called. Even when defining it in the static constructor to make sure it is started before anything else.

**Can anyone please help me with this?**

Kind regards
andla